# GMAPPING: How to mark 'out of range' laserscan as free-space

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, gmapping, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a SICK TIM 300 Laserscanner with the gmapping node to create a Map.
But whenever the Laserscanner can not see an obstacle at a certain angle (because the obstacles are out of range), gmapping marks these areas as 'unknown'.
But the Laserscanner not seeing anything at a certain angle, means there is no obstacle within the measuring-range (in my case: 4m). As a result gmapping should mark these areas as free.

How can I solve this problem?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS hydro.
The Laserscanner marks these 'out-of-range'-areas as 'distance = 0m', the header from the /scan - message tells that the minimum distance is 0.05m.

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222692/gmapping:-how-to-mark-%27out-of-range%27-laserscan-as-free-space/) by [Alex1209](https://answers.ros.org/users/25356/alex1209/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you take a look at the gmapping [page](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) there're two parameters called `maxUrange` and `maxRange`. I quote: "If regions with no obstacles within the range of the sensor should appear as free space in the map, set maxUrange < maximum range of the real sensor <= maxRange".

So, if you want that region appears as free space, you have to set your `maxUrange` under the maximum range of the real sensor (which is the `maxRange`parameter).

---

Originally posted by [S.Prieto](https://answers.ros.org/users/23156/s.prieto/) with karma: 258 on 2015-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex1209](https://answers.ros.org/users/25356/alex1209/) on 2015-12-17**:
Thank you very much :D
It's that easy. Now the map looks way better.

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-05-19**:
what is the unit of maxUrange and max range?